# Using sed to edit multiple lines of text

Tags: macos, sed

I'm on Mac OS X (using Apple sed not GNU sed) and I have a file with text like this.

```
            <key>wolf die se0000.bmp</key>
            <dict>
                <key>frame</key>
                <string>{{288,224},{44,68}}</string>
            </dict>
            <key>wolf die se0001.bmp</key>
            <dict>
                <key>frame</key>
                <string>{{288,224},{44,68}}</string>
            </dict>
            <key>wolf die w0000.bmp</key>
            <dict>
                <key>frame</key>
                <string>{{288,224},{44,68}}</string>
            </dict>
```

I want to copy paste some sections and modify the key so the file looks like this:

```
        <key>wolf die se0000.bmp</key>
        <dict>
            <key>frame</key>
            <string>{{288,224},{44,68}}</string>
        </dict>
        <key>wolf stand se0000.bmp</key>
        <dict>
            <key>frame</key>
            <string>{{288,224},{44,68}}</string>
        </dict>
        <key>wolf die se0001.bmp</key>
        <dict>
            <key>frame</key>
            <string>{{288,224},{44,68}}</string>
        </dict>
        <key>wolf die w0000.bmp</key>
        <dict>
            <key>frame</key>
            <string>{{288,224},{44,68}}</string>
        </dict>
        <key>wolf stand w0000.bmp</key>
        <dict>
            <key>frame</key>
            <string>{{288,224},{44,68}}</string>
        </dict>
```

So, I'm trying to use a sed command like this to achieve the desired effect (test.plist is the file with the 1st segment of text):

```
sed -E -n '
1h
1!H
$ {
g
s/(<key>wolf die )([a-z]{1,2})(0000)(.*<\/dict>)/\1\2\3\4\n<key>wolf stand \2 0000\4/
p
}
' test.plist
```

I'm not getting the desired result. I expect it to terminate after seeing the first </dict> tag and do the replacement and then follow, but my sed expertise is quite poor to achieve this.

The actual output I'm getting is:

```
            <key>wolf die se0000.bmp</key>
            <dict>
                <key>frame</key>
                <string>{{288,224},{44,68}}</string>
            </dict>
            <key>wolf die se0001.bmp</key>
            <dict>
                <key>frame</key>
                <string>{{288,224},{44,68}}</string>
            </dict>
            <key>wolf die w0000.bmp</key>
            <dict>
                <key>frame</key>
                <string>{{288,224},{44,68}}</string>
            </dict>n<key>wolf stand se 0000.bmp</key>
            <dict>
                <key>frame</key>
                <string>{{288,224},{44,68}}</string>
            </dict>
            <key>wolf die se0001.bmp</key>
            <dict>
                <key>frame</key>
                <string>{{288,224},{44,68}}</string>
            </dict>
            <key>wolf die w0000.bmp</key>
            <dict>
                <key>frame</key>
                <string>{{288,224},{44,68}}</string>
            </dict>
```

How do I correct this?

PS: I'm not getting the newline with this Apple sed as well, but I'm thinking that should be a small fix

Comment: You should use a XML parser  for that.

Comment: sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line, for any other text manipulation you should use awk as the resulting script will be simpler, more robust, more easily extensible, and often briefer. If you tell us what you're trying to do, we can help - expecting us to guess from your posted output and non-working sed script is not a good approach.

Comment: @EdMorton I have briefly expressed what I wanted to do. Quote "copy paste a section (from key tag to dict tag), and then change the key (key tag) of that section". Am I being too brief? Is it possible to post an answer on how to do this with awk?

Answer (score 3):

Use a proper XML handling tool, e.g. [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2):

```
open file.xml ;

for //key[contains(., 'wolf die')][contains(., '0000')] {
    $n := xcp . after ./following-sibling::dict[1] ;
    set $n/text() xsh:subst(., ' die ', ' stand ') ;
    xcp ./following-sibling::dict[1] after $n ;
}

save :b ;
```